# how to safely join strings to a path in php?

Tags: php, string, security, code-injection

I have a constant beginning of a string, and a variable ending, how can I secure the string so that is doesn't create a step-back (or step-up) in case the string I inject contains

```
../
```

Here is a short sample code:

```
$dir = 'my/base/path/';
$file = $dir . $userSelectedFilename;
unlink($file);
```

If `$userSelectedFilename` would be `'../../myFileName'` I assume that would cause my script to actually try to unlink something two directory levels up `my/myFilename` which is clearly not something I want to allow, I want to keep it under the basepath `my/base/path/` under all circumstances.

Comment: my/base/path/../../myFileName - I might be being thick but on my server at least that wont go up a level it will just result in an error!

Comment: use `realpath` function to eliminate symlink such as `.`, `..`, `/`, `//`, etc as appeared in the Gumbo's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the the following, and only the following method:

```
<?
$dir = 'my/base/path/';
$file = $dir . $userSelectedFilename;
if(strpos(realpath($file),realpath($dir)) === 0) && is_file($file)) { // beware of the three ===
  unlink($file);
}
```

Why?

It is safe to rely on realpath to find out the real location of a file which eliminates directory traversal / multibyte double-dots etc.

After that we check whether the beginning of the reapath of the file is really the beginning of our expacted directory (strpos).

After that we also check whether the file is really a file and not some symlink pointing elswhere or something like that.

I have seen character eliminating solutions been broken by multibyte strings and similar attacks.

This method so far far withstands all of these.

Comment: I see your point. If I were to disallow dots all together in my $userSelectedFilename would that protect me? Or could the slash alone produce directory traversing?

Comment: you dont need to check for dots any longer, the solution above takes care of this. the user can specify folder1/folder1/../ and will be in folder 1. it is okay as long as the user stays inside the specified directory.

Comment: Yes, but if I only allow safe strings to begin with I only have to do it in one place (I'm lazy) =) So will no-dots-policy keep me safe?

Comment: if your strings are transliterated to ascii and contain no double dots and the target is really a file and not a symlink or diretory and also all directoryies in that tree, then yes - you probably are.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out those characters by doing something like:

```
$file = preg_match("/\.\.\//", "", $file)
```

which will remove occurrences of the string `../`

And just a side note, you should probably find a different way of allowing users to select files to delete rather than allowing them to input the path as a string, maybe by showing them a directory listing of files they can delete or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, I will use regexp. As for your sidenote - that's a good suggestion but that is not what I am doing, I just simplified my case a bit to focus on the problem. Many thanks!

Comment: true, it filters the path. but it does not really check whether the file is in the directory. i know this is not part of the answer,but it has to be kept in mind. what about a symlink inside the directory pointing outside?

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to validate the string for `../` or `/../` and not accepting the string if the regex returns true:

```
function validatePath($path) {
    if(preg_match('#\/\.\.\/#',$path))
        return False;
}
```

Comment: throw in a multi byte .. and you are doomed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this "`my/base/path/../../dir/`", if you want "real" path use this :

```
 echo realpath($dir."../../dir/"); // my/dir
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: true, but its also important on how to work with the result of realpath in this case. i have seen it done wrong in many cases...